# Executing select during bulk insert - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

While trying to select from a table at a time when multiple insert are being made to the same table, the select statement times out. How can this be avoided

Comment: Is your question coming from the context of an application, or are you observing this in the Oracle client locally?

Comment: this is in context from application. but if i execute same query in db.. i get delay in select execution

Comment: Writers don't block readers in Oracle so it's not obvious what the issue is.  Are you sure you are using the Oracle database (and not a different database that happens to be owned by Oracle Corp)?  What is the query waiting on?  Are you doing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` rather than a plain `SELECT`?  Does the query actually run efficiently when there is no other activity on the table?

Comment: Show results from procedure show_space in this article https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:231414051079